# How do the additional guards work in Framing Frame day 3?

Tags: payday-2

I just completed Framing Frame on full stealth (difficulty hard). Had to replay Day 3 a few times and I noticed that I can down 2 or 3 guards without any ill effects. (Assuming I answer their pagers and hide the bodies.) But after that additional guards arrive.

When do the guards arrive exactly? How many? Is there a difference between difficulty levels? And, as it seems that some of them leave after a while, how many will stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to kill up to 3 guards without any ill effects. Once you kill the fourth guard, one additional guard will show up. This functions the same way as it does on Framing Frame day 1. I don't know for certain if there are many locations the guard will spawn from, but he does appear from the very bottom of the staircase (the part that isn't accessible).

While stealthed, Bain will announce the arrival of the extra guard. Once he appears, he will inspect the entire place (he follows a similar path to other guards). He is noticeable because he stops to talk into his walkie-talkie and report that things are clear. Once he has inspected the entire place (takes a few minutes), he will leave. Again, this function the same way on day 1.

To the best of my knowledge, this functions the same on all difficulties (although I believe there are less guards to begin with on lower difficulties), but truthfully I've never completed the map on Normal and it has been a long time since I've done anything less than Overkill. Speaking of *to the best of my knowledge*, this information all comes from hours of playing; however, I haven't played the game in about 6 months, so it may be patched (Overkill don't explicitly mention **every** change they make in their patch notes unfortunately).

Since this functionality wasn't in the game to begin with, I went through the patch notes but couldn't find much to support any of this unfortunately. Here's all I got:

#### [April 10, 2014](http://steamcommunity.com/games/218620/announcements/detail/1730814915329823621):

> - During stealth Bain now informs the crew if a new guard is about to arrive
> - Changed the timer on the spawning patrol guards to make it more balanced for each difficulty

Comment: So, it's just the one guy who comes in (and later leaves) and the rest are those who survived earlier?